# How to make image nested in div fill the remaining space on the page?

Tags: html, css

I'm learning CSS and got stuck creating a layout that contains a header and an image that fills the rest of the screen. Using the following code, I'm able to achieve what I'm looking for:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.image-container {
  flex: 1;
}

img {
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <h1>Test Page</h1>
      </div>
<!--       <div class="image-container"> --> 
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/300"/>
<!--      </div> -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now the problem is that I want to wrap the image element into a div as I'd like to position an overlay on top of the image. As soon as I nest the `img` within a `div`, the resizing doesn't work properly anymore. If the screen is wide, the image overflows to the bottom, creating a vertical scrollbar.

I've tried a lot of things, but nothing's worked so far. Can you explain to me why introducing the `div` (`image-container`) changes the layout and how to make it behave like the version without the `div`? That'd be great, thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I want the image to be displayed exactly like in the snippet I posted. It should be as large as possible, but only so large that the whole image is still visible and nothing is cropped. For a wide window, there should be blank bars left and right of the image. For a narrow but tall window, there should be blank bars above/beyond the image.

My issue is that as soon as I add the `<div class="image-container">`, the image always takes the whole width. For a wide window, I get scrollbars and can't see the whole image anymore. I'd like to know how I can get the image to scale like in the version without the additional `<div>`. I'd also like to understand why adding the `<div>` changes how the image is scaled.

**EDIT 2:**

Someone suggested to add `overflow: hidden;` on `.image-container`, but deleted their answer. This does in fact work (`overflow: hidden/scroll/auto;` work, `overflow: visible;` does not), but now I'm completely confused to why that's the case. I thought that `overflow` would control if overflow is visible, but wouldn't affect the size of the content being displayed. In this case though, it seems like the `overflow` property does have an effect on the size of the picture being displayed. That's weird and if anyone knows what's going on, please let me know!

Comment: This change in behavior is due to the rule `display: flex` only applying to it's immediate children. When you uncomment out your div. The style of container now applies only to `<div class="header">` and `<div class="image-container">` and not your `<img>` tag

Comment: Alright, so the `<div class="image-container">` should have the correct size, right? Why doesn't the image get exactly that size even though I've set it to `width: 100%; height: 100%`?

Comment: this is how i understood you , is this what you want ? https://jsfiddle.net/twyfmbvp/3/

Answer (score 0):

Flex is already helping the image take up as much space as possible, so the `height: 100%` and `width: 100%` were causing the image to grow.

For getting something to appear on top of the image, I would recommend [looking into](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) `position: absolute` or `position: relative`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.image-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Test Page</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Seems like my problem description wasn't good. I want the image to grow, so (I guess) I need the `width: 100%; height: 100%` on the image. I edited the question, hopefully making what I want to do more clear.

Comment: If I get the image to scale properly with the `<div class="image-container">`, I'm pretty sure that I can do the overlay by myself using `position: relative / absolute`.